# Possible to use Promise.in with infinite time?

Tags: promise, raku

Is there a direct way to use `Promise.in` (or other sub/method/class) to achieve an indefinite amount of time? In other words the Promise is never resolved.

Currently I'm checking the `$time` when the promise is kept to see if an indefinite time was requested (indicated by negative or 0 value) and preventing the react block from exiting.

Is isn't a terrible solution, but is there are more idiomatic way of achieving this?

```
my $time=0;
react {
    whenever Promise.in($time) {
          #check if time is 0
          done if $time > 0;
    }
    whenever signal(SIGINT) {
        done;
    }

    #whenever Supply...{
    #}
}
```

Comment: Is `done if $time <= 0` supposed to be `done if $time > 0`? What do you mean by "achieve an indefinite amount of time"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: hmm you are right my logic is backward. I'll fix that. If I want to run my program for 10 seconds (`$time=10`), the promise will fire as expected. If I want to run the code forever, I can't make a promise via `Promise.in` to not fire. I either have to specify a very large time, or add  extra tests as I have done. This is fine, just wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually pass `Inf` to Promise.in, like this:

```
await Promise.in(Inf);
say "never happens";
```

Comment: gee, I can't believe that didn't cross my mind! that's exactly what I was after. Thanks!

Comment: Heh. That was the first thing I thought of. But I tried it and got an exception. (Turns out it was added recently.) I thought you maybe tried it then decided it wasn't worth mentioning. I came up with a workaround (`whenever $time && Promise.in($time)`). It was poor so I decided to provide links to a bug report about having an `Inf` candidate or why there wasn't one. Also, if there was a `$?MAXINT` or similar as a suitable workaround. Studying the latter led to me posting [an issue](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/3152). I returned here and posted an answer -- then saw timotimo's. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
whenever Promise.new {
```

pretty much gives you a promise that will never be kept, so the associated code will never fire.  Not sure why you would do that, though.

Comment: I guess I was hoping there was some parameter I could give to `Promise.in` that would allow a definite time (resolve) or indefinite time (never resolve) to make my react block tidy. That way I could use the same code without a special test. Maybe my question isn't clear.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a promise that is never fulfilled, simply running `Promise.new` gives you one.

Somebody could still call `.keep` on that promise, unless you [obtain a vow](http://docs.perl6.org/type/Promise#method_vow) to prevent that.